# Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events fedora

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, watch, angular-cli

This is not a duplicate:

I am using Intellij `Angular CLI` on Fedora 24

`Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.`

Is the output in my console when the project is generating. `NodeWatcher` makes my IDE painfully slow and am hoping `WatchMan` is the answer.

Full message:

```
/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng init --name=TestProject
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
installing ng2
```

So far I did `sudo dnf install inotify-tools-3.14-10.fc24` This is like Homebrew but for linux from my understanding. For more information here is the link [info](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html)

I even downloaded homebrew on my Fedora machine but it downloaded just couldn't get it to work.

`npm -v 3.9.6`
`node -v v4.4.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install Watchman from source. Clone or download it from https://github.com/facebook/watchman. 
Be sure You have installed: Autoconf, Automake and Python-dev (or Python-devel) software.
In terminal run commands:
1. git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git (or download zip file from link above) , 
2. cd watchman , 
3. git checkout v4.6.0 , 
4. ./autogen.sh , 
5. ./configure , 
6. make , 
7. sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
```

This means that we don’t have a tool called watchman installed. This tool helps Angular
CLI when it needs to monitor files in your filesystem for changes. If you’re running OSX,
it’s recommended to install it using Homebrew with the following command

```
$ brew install watchman
```